# codeigniter "after-method" equivalent of _remap()

Tags: php, codeigniter

If CodeIgniter has `_remap()` that gets called *before* it touches any method in a controller, is there an *after-method* equivalent that gets called after a method is called?

The scenario is that

1. one usually pre-checks stuff like login credentials in either the constructor or remap of that controller. this is the *pre-method* area.
2. After that, one builds the page data inside a method.
3. Then one loads and displays a view/template by calling the template parser or loading a view.

I would like to have that third step automated in somewhat an automatic *after-method* function which can be inherited by all my controllers so i won't have to call the parser/loader every time i make a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter got a feature called "[hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)". I'm sure that's what you looking for.

From the [hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) page;
The following is a list of available hook points.

> **pre_system**
>   Called very early during system execution. Only the benchmark and hooks class have been loaded at this point. No routing or other processes have happened.
>
> **pre_controller**
>   Called immediately prior to any of your controllers being called. All base classes, routing, and security checks have been done.
>
> **post_controller_constructor**
>   Called immediately after your controller is instantiated, but prior to any method calls happening.
>
> **post_controller**
>   Called immediately after your controller is fully executed.
>
> **display_override**
>   Overrides the _display() function, used to send the finalized page to the web browser at the end of system execution. This permits you to use your own display methodology. Note that you will need to reference the CI superobject with $this->CI =& get_instance() and then the finalized data will be available by calling $this->CI->output->get_output()
>
> **cache_override**
>   Enables you to call your own function instead of the _display_cache() function in the output class. This permits you to use your own cache display mechanism.
>
> **post_system**
>   Called after the final rendered page is sent to the browser, at the end of system execution after the finalized data is sent to the browser.